# A magma-related Lava pun

Tags: verbs, puns

Some days ago I bumped into a [non-official, Italian version of the song for the Lava short](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j2B4S3HSfEc) by Pixar about a volcano that keeps waiting for someone to love. The original song makes a pun between the words *lava* and *love*. This version tries to keep the pun with the following verses:

> Io so che nel mondo per me c'è un amore
>   che magma con tutto il suo cuore.

I enjoyed the song very much but my knowledge of Italian is very very limited so I could not identify the pun in *magma*. Now I think I know what the pun is, but I don't want to bias your answers, so I ask, what's the intended pun in the verses above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pun lies in the fact that in Italian the word *magma* sounds a bit like *m'ama*, the contracted form of *mi ama*, that is, “loves me”.

So the quoted verse means “I know that in the world for me there is a love who magma/loves me with all his heart”.

Comment: This is the pun I thought. After figuring that out I checked the lyrics in the video and there it is written "che m'agma con tutto il suo cuore" (note the apostrophe), which reinforces the pun with "m'ama" or "mi ama".